# Should we tag by model number?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This link,](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/318/what-are-the-advantages-of-the-canon-580ex-ii-over-the-430ex-ii) amongst others, discuss the merits of particular pieces of equipment.  My inclination is to tag all of these with the hardware listed in the question, but I wanted to make sure that was kosher before going on a rampage.

Answer (score 6):

I would vote for tagging by manufacturers only. Search function can do the rest (filtering out specific models).

Answer (score 5):

I'd say that, in an ideal world, questions specific to a particular model would get tagged with that model. Questions specific to a particular line or brand would get tagged with that model or brand. Questions not specific to a model, line or brand would get no gear-specific tags.

So, for example:

- "What is the sensor resolution of a Nikon D90?". Tags: nikon-d90 nikon
- "What is the best zoom lens for a Nikon camera?" Tags: nikon
- "What polarizing filter should I get?" Tags: filter (nothing brand-specific)

This gives you specificity when you need it.

Enforcing this is another matter.

Comment: The problem with this is you end up with too many tags. There are probably a hundred tags just accounting for all the variety of different camera models from the major manufacturers. Let alone all the variations of lens models numbers dating back...decades. I think brand and item names are ok, but model numbers are extremely fine grained. A combination of search and tag can take care of the necessary specificity.

Comment: If you end up with hundreds of tags, but those tags accurately represent what they describe, why is that a problem?

Comment: Because you're limited to only 5 tags, and if you've got to give specific details of a complicated question, as well as all of the more general variants related to the specific tags you'll soon be limited. If you're after something specific you can search.

Answer (score 2):

+1 Excellent question. I do think it needs some discussion though, as we could end up with a tremendous amount of tags (and variations of the same tag) if we are not careful. The thread you linked could be tagged in a variety of ways:

**Speedlite, Speed-lite, 580EX-II, 580EXII, 430EX-II, 430EXII, etc.**

That is too many possible tags. If we limited it to brand and product name, things would be a lot simpler:

**Canon, Speedlight**

Comment: is it as simple as deciding no dashes are necessary in these types of tags, or should we identify the actual product name on the manufacturer's site?

Comment: I actually think gabr's answer is better. Tag with manufacturers (and possibly equipment name, like Speedlight) only, but not model numbers. Let search figure out the rest. That will keep it clean and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Model-specific tags could be useful to group questions *highly*-specific to particular models, however…

If there are better tags relating to the *content* of the question, use them first.  For example, that question is *about* flashes in general and Speedlites at the next "step" narrower in context, so both [speedlite] and [camera-flash] are preferred to model numbers, with [camera-flash] being much more important than the other.  (Though I'm not sure why it's not named [flash].)

Similarly, a question with more than 3 model numbers – and 3 is pushing it – is less about each specific model.  Merely mentioning a specific model isn't enough to warrant a tag.

We can use [tag synonyms](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) as the site progresses and tag names settle down.  This will alleviate dupes in the form of [canon-580ex-ii] vs [canon-580exii] vs [canon-580ex2], and so forth.

Additionally, producer/publisher/manufacturer prefixes are helpful whenever tagging as specifically as this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with a lot of what's already been said by others. Here's my thoughts:

- That question does not need tagging for specific models as it's more about Canon's range of speedlites and choosing one flash from it.
- If we had a *specific* question about one type of flash (eg. How do I enable function XYZ on my `[canon] [580exii]`) then they should be tagged more precisely.

Additionally, what are we going to do about things like the Canon xxxD/Digital Rebel series, that have different names in different parts of the world?

Comment: I think that as a user, if I wanted to buy a 580, I would start with the 580 tag.  I would hope that that post showed up underneath that category, as it affects my decision to purchase it or not.

Comment: If you knew you wanted to buy a 580 then I guess you'd be looking for a different kind of question to what you'd be looking for if you didn't know which Canon flash to buy?

Comment: There is a question about Canon xxxD/Digital Rebel series - http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/258/canon-body-names-in-tags/